# Sum columns on different granularity

Tags: sql, tableau-desktop

| id | buying_id | name | firm | type | item | sales ($) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | A | aa | individual | apple | 10 |
| 1 | 101 | A | aa | individual | banana | 11 |
| 2 | 102 | C | bb | firm | apple | 12 |
| 3 | 102 | D | bb | firm | apple | 13 |
| 4 | 102 | E | bb | firm | apple | 14 |
| 5 | 103 | F | aa | individual | apple | 15 |

I have a transaction table likes this:

- **id** is associated with **name,** each person will have their own unique id.
- **buying_id** is associated with the **type**:

  - for example, the first two rows indicate that this person is buying on his own;
  - id 2, 3, 4 are three people from the same company sharing the same buying_id.
- **sales** is associated with **buying_id**

  - row 3 and 4 can be understood as C bought $12 apples and D bought $13 apples.

I want to summarize the table by aggregating the sales by buying_id, however, I also would like to keep individual's information and have 0 on the sum if the buying unit has appeared once. For example, if I aggregate all the rows using the table above, I would like to have the following output.

| id | buying_id | name | firm | type | sum(sales) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | A | aa | individual | 21 |
| 2 | 102 | C | bb | firm | 39 |
| 3 | 102 | D | bb | firm | 0 |
| 4 | 102 | E | bb | firm | 0 |
| 5 | 103 | F | aa | individual | 15 |

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Dale K I am stuck at the stage change 39 to 0 when same buying_id has already appeared previously.

Comment: Show us the code you have. And tag the single RDBMS of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I tried sum(sales) group by everything except for item, and created a temp table to store aggregated numbers. In this table I also have a row_number() partition by buying_id function to flag the number of appearance of the buying_id.

Then I used a case when function to select everything in the temp table, and created a new column
case when row_number = 1 then sales else 0 end as cleaned_sales.